# Cannot Install Parallels Tools on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, parallels, ubuntu-18.04

I can't install Parallels Tools on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Here is the error log:

```
Started installation of Parallels Guest Tools version '13.3.0.43321'

Thu Apr 26 21:45:11 PDT 2018
Start installation or upgrade of Guest Tools
new version of parallels tools
Installed Guest Tools were not found
Perform installation into the /usr/lib/parallels-tools directory
cat: /usr/lib/parallels-tools/kmods/../version: No such file or directory
make: Entering directory '/usr/lib/parallels-tools/kmods'
cd prl_eth/pvmnet && make
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/lib/parallels-tools/kmods/prl_eth/pvmnet'
make -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-20-generic/build M=/usr/lib/parallels-tools/kmods/prl_eth/pvmnet
make[2]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-20-generic'
Makefile:976: "Cannot use CONFIG_STACK_VALIDATION=y, please install libelf-dev, libelf-devel or elfutils-libelf-devel"
  CC [M]  /usr/lib/parallels-tools/kmods/prl_eth/pvmnet/pvmnet.o
  LD [M]  /usr/lib/parallels-tools/kmods/prl_eth/pvmnet/prl_eth.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
FATAL: modpost: GPL-incompatible module prl_eth.ko uses GPL-only symbol 'sev_enable_key'
scripts/Makefile.modpost:92: recipe for target '__modpost' failed
make[3]: *** [__modpost] Error 1
Makefile:1555: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make[2]: *** [modules] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-20-generic'
/usr/lib/parallels-tools/kmods/prl_eth/pvmnet/Makefile.v26:11: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/lib/parallels-tools/kmods/prl_eth/pvmnet'
Makefile.kmods:34: recipe for target 'installme' failed
make: *** [installme] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/usr/lib/parallels-tools/kmods'
Error: could not build kernel modules
Error: failed to install kernel modules
Error: failed to install Parallels Guest Tools!
Please, look at /var/log/parallels-tools-install.log file for more information.
```

However, when installing Parallels Tools on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, everything went fine.

Answer (score 2):

Parallels Tools fail to build required kernel module on kernels 4.15+.

See https://forum.parallels.com/threads/fail-to-build-kernel-modules-on-linux-kernel-v4-15.343748/

As a workaround, you can try to downgrade to 4.14, but I don't see any kernel packages with precompiled 4.14. You might need to recompile or see, if any previous dailies had 4.14 (not recommended tho).

Solution: wait for Parallels to release update.

Comment: See here how to downgrade the kernel: https://bartsimons.me/installing-parallels-tools-on-ubuntu-18-04/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have fully working Parallels Tools on distribution that is using the newest kernel you can use this fix I made:
https://gist.github.com/rudolfratusinski/a4d9e3caff11a4d9d81d2e84abc9afbf

It is taking into consideration most recent changes to the kernel (timer.h in this case)

Answer (score 1):

Parallels 13.3.1-43365 and later support Ubuntu 18.04. Source: https://kb.parallels.com/124262

Comment: The Parallels Tools installation still fails with that version here.